# Как cоздать функцию перевода русских букв в транслит?

Tags: php

Как можно создать функцию, которая заменит русские буквы на английские (транслит)?
Например, имя `Артур`

**INPUT**

```
<?php
function func() {
//
}
$text='Артур';
echo func($text);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Artur
```

И еще буквы `ч, щ, э, ъ, ю, и, й, ц, с` как можно заменить правильно на английский?

Comment: Есть ГОСТ (вроде ГОСТ 7.79-2000), при помощи которого можно транслит сделать. Вам этого хватит? Пример на js можно посмотреть [здесь](http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/27347-nadezhnyjj-dvukhstoronnijj-translit.html#post168115)

Comment: @ВОРОН спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужна функция `str_replace();`

```
function convertRUcharacters($str) {
    $from = array('а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я','А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я');
    $to = array('a','b','v','g','d','e','e','zh','z','i','i','k','l','m','n','o','p','r','s','t','u','f','kh','cz','ch','sh','shh','','y','','e','yu','ya','A','B','V','G','D','E','E','ZH','Z','I','I','K','L','M','N','O','P','R','S','T','U','F','KH','CZ','CH','SH','SHH','','Y','','E','YU','YA');
    return str_replace($from, $to, $str);
}
echo convertRUcharacters('Артур');
```

Однако будьте осторожны с кодировками. UTF8, WIN1251 и т.д. Могут понадобиться функции работы с многобайтовыми строками (http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.mbstring.php)

Comment: Если ответ Вас устроил - пометьте его как принятый (зеленая галочка у ответа). Чтобы было больше закрытых вопросов. Спасибо

Comment: а зачем Ш и Щ одинаково переводить? Можно же по госту сделать - и будет нормальное (однозначное) преобразование в обе стороны.

Comment: @cyadvert Кстати, а откуда могут взяться проблемы с 1251, она же однобайтовая. И с utf-8 то же проблем не будет, там же в массиве отлично будут лежать двухбайтные символы и оно именно их и будет искать, а utf-8 так устроен, что середины символов отличаются от начал и пересечения границы символа при подобной замене быть не может

Comment: @Mike, да, верно. Я просто перечислил кодировки... не более... для автора. Чтобы, если не сработает, знал, куда копать :)